# Is it possible to use .AsParallel Extension Method in PCL?

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library, portable-class-library

I have a problem in a Portable Class Library class. It seems I cannot use `.AsParallel()` extension method although `System.Linq` is referenced. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PortableClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            var list = new List<String>();                
        }
    }
}
```

`list` hasn't `AsParallel()` method, it has only `AsQueryable` and `AsEnumerable`.

Target frameworks are .NET 4.5 and highr, Phone 8, Windows Store App (Win 8) and higher. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413237%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) lists the method as supported in Portable Class Libraries. Also it is supported in .NET 4 & 4.5 and Windows Store Apps from version 8. The only platform I was not able to find an implementation for is Windows Phone 8.
So I suspect that this is the reason why it is not available in your PCL. I verified this in a test project and as soon as you remove the WP8 platform for the PCL, you can call AsParallel.